# How to know that last activity of certain type X is closed?

Tags: android

I would like to run some action when all activities of certain type X are closed. The first idea is to have some global counter, that is decremented each time activity X is closed, and once the counter is 0, run some action. Assuming that process can be killed, the counter have to be persisted. But one more issue remains - imagine that activity X can crash (due to some bug in code), and in this case I'll not decrement the counter.

Any idea how to implement it in robust way?

Comment: I'm not very sure, but won't onDestroy called everytime? also when an activity crashes?

Comment: If activity crashed, the onDestroy will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by 'closed', but you should be able to use the Activity Lifecycle callbacks to accomplish what you are asking.

There is a diagram on the following page that shows how the Activity Lifecycle is implemented:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: i read it, but i wasn't sure if onDestroy will be called if an activity crashes?!

Comment: When user clicks BACK button, the activity is closed. This is what I mean... I know about Activity Lifecycle, but can't figure out how to accomplish what I want in robust way.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can have a global counter for this.

Maybe the good place for it is in the Application class?

Or u just save you counter in a file and reset it every time you start your application (in a very first activity).

You can also try to save it in shared preferences.

But there is still the problem with crashes. I have just an idea. There is ACRA-library for crash-logging. Take a look in it, how do they catch the crashes.

So you can just write a method for decrementing your counter. And call it from onDestroy() or if a crash occurs.